# Run length encoding in C++

Tags: c++, string, compression

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

string compression(const string & str){
    int i = str.size();
    string letters;
    letters[0] = str[0];
    for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j){
        int count = 1;
        while (str[j] == str[j+1]){
            count++;
            j++;
        }
        letters.push_back('0' + count);
        letters.push_back(str[j]);
    }
    return letters;
}

int main(){
    string input;
    char c;
    try {
        cout << "Enter the data to be compressesed: "<< endl;
        cin >> input;
        for (int z = 0; z < input.length(); ++z){
            c = input.at(z);
        }
        if (!(c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')){
            throw runtime_error("error: invalid input");
        }
    }
    catch (runtime_error& excpt){
        cout << excpt.what() <<endl;
        return 0;
    }
    cout << "The compressed data is " << compression(input) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The expected output is , repeated for each run of characters. Here  is the amount of times  is repeated in sequence.

Some examples:

aaeeeeae = 2a4e1a1e

rr44errre = invalid input

eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee = 21e

the code works properly only if the character is repeated consecutively 9 times or less. for values of 10 and more the input is other symbols.
For example it stays blank for 10, so if input is 'aaaaaaaaaabb',output just would be 'a2b' instead of '10a2b'. For 11 its outputs ';',
so if input is 'aaaaaaaaaaabb', output is ';a2b' for some reason.

So my question is, how do i make the pushback work for all numbers and not just from 0-9?

Thank you for your time if u've gotten to here. ^^

Comment: Can you please add code with proper indentation?

Comment: So why do you think that is? Assuming count = 11, what do you expect '0' + count to be?

Comment: Mayur, I hope this is better ( im still a beginner);

Comment: Don't use `c` tag for question about `c++`

Comment: Jakub, well I initially thought it would be 11 but i guess not.

Comment: '0' + count produces a single character, it will never produce the two character string "11", you may need to use/write some function to do that

Comment: @jakub_d, any ideas/hints on what I need to add?

Comment: Yes, here's a hint: open your C++ book to the chapter that explains how to use `std::stringstream` and read it.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, i have read about it but i dont understand how it could be implemented here... would u mind helping out code wise?

Comment: std::stringstream -- amongst other things, lets you convert any `int` to a string. You also need to convert an `int` that represents the number of consecutive chars, to a string, to be added to your encoded string. Which part of this, exactly, are you unclear about?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, Yes, i understand the situation and it is all clear, I just dont know how to translate that to c++, thank you very much btw, really appreciate it !

Comment: Of course you know how to translate that into C++, after all, you said that you "read about it", so you must, therefore, know how to: 1) Create a new `std::stringstream`, 2) use the `<<` operator to format an `int` value into the string stream, 3) Obtain the formatted `std::string` from it, and, finally, add the formatted `std::string`, containing the count formatted as a string, to your existing string. Unless the shown code above is not your code, you already know how to do the third step, and your C++ book must have many examples of doing the first two.

Answer (score 3):

If you can use c++11 or newer your function `compression` could look like:

```
string compression(const string & str){
    int i = str.size();
    string letters;

    for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j){
        int count = 1;
        while (str[j] == str[j+1]){
            count++;
            j++;
        }
        letters += std::to_string(count);
        letters.push_back(str[j]);
    }
    return letters;
}
```